# Using 1 array to implement 2 for loop programs

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that every count of 2 it changes the value to "Open" or "1".

1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10

0-1-0-1-0-1-0-1-0-1 ** Something like this ** and after that in every three count it changes into "Open" or "1".

but if the box is already "open" or "1". It should "close" or "0".

and so on up to 150 count.

my problem is that i cant make the output show into one array.I have no problem doing it if it was a different array..Help...

```
int[] box = new int [150];
int b = 0;    
for (a = 1; a < box.length; a++) {
    if (a % 2 == 0) {
        box[b] = 1;
    }    
    else {
        box[b] = 0;
    }
}
for (int c = 1; c < box.length; c++) {
    if (c % 3 == 0) {
        if (box[b] == 1) {
            box[b] = 0;
        }
        else {
            box[b] = 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        box[b] = 0;
    }
    System.out.print(box[b]); //putting the result here only result in 001001001;
}
/*System.out.print(box[b]); -- Putting it outside results in just zero.
```

How can I combine the two for-loops into one array? I hope this makes sense to all of you. A different approach is also okay as long as the for loop and array are used.
Output program should be 011101011101 something like this when the two are together...

**This is the 2nd program i did now please check cause i was suppose to add all the "0"'s and all the "1"'s after the program is executed i just want to know how to add it.Putting it inside the loop will loop it to 150 times**

```
int box [] =  new int [150];

int ones= 0;
int zero= 0;


for(int a= 0;a<box.length;a = a+2){
box[a]  = 1;
for(int b =0;b<box.length;b = b+3){
if(box[b]==1){
box[b] = 0;
zero++;
}
else{
box[b] = 1;
one++;
}
System.out.print("No. of ones : " + one); /* putting it here loops the additions to up    to 150 and resulting to thousands of ones */
}
System.out.print(No. of ones: " + one); /* putting it here will result to 0 and loops up to 150 counting up to thousands of zero */
}

for(int i =0; i < box.length; i++){
System.out.print(box[i]); Resulting to 00111 - up to 150 /* the next count is by 4 is this enough to for loops to add it by 5 the next and then add it by 6 then 7 and up to 150 counts till hitting the "Open" or "1"?
System.out.print("No. of one: " + sum); } -- putting it here will only result to 0
```

Thanks hope you understand this questions (theres a lot of them)and i'm confused

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over `a` and later over `c` but assigning to `box[b]`. And `b` remains `0`, so you keep assigning to `box[0]`. You should assign to `box[a]` and `box[c]`.

In addition, you should start your for loops from 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one loop. the question is only in creating correct condition.

```
int box[]=new int [150];
for (int i=1; i< box.length+1; i++) {
    boolean condition = i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0;
    box[i-1] = condition ? 1 : 0;
    System.out.print(box[i-1]);
}
```

the condition checks whether index is divided by 2 or 3.

Comment: I think you should explain what was his mistake and not make for him the code. Also, I don't understand why are you initializing a to 1 and not 0.

Comment: I've start from 1 to simplify condition expression. Of course, it's better to start from 0.

Comment: But he wanted that if the index is a multiple 2 it will be set to 1, not if it doesn't. Also, your code is incorrect, because if the number is a multiple of 2 *and* 3, it should be set to be 0.

Comment: || is 'or', but not 'xor'. So, for 6 (%2=0 and %3=0), the condition will be true.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over `a` and `c`, but you are assigning `box[b]`. Because `b` remains `0`, you are every time assigns `1` or `0` to the first place in the array (`box[0]`). You should index your arrays with your iterators (`box[a]` and `box[c]`) so every time you will refer to different place in the array.

In addition, you are iterating every time through the whole array. Another approach is to "jump" over the indexes in the array that you don't want, by doing this for example this:

```
for(a=0;a<box.length;a = a + 2)
    box[a]=1;
```

This will only iterate through all of the even numbers in your array.

One last thing, you can use `box[c] = box[c] ^ 1` (`^` means `XOR`) in your second loop instead of using `if(box[c]==1)`. This will remove the if statement while keep doing what you wanted.

**Edit:**

For the printing you should use for loop that iterates through the array and print every place in the array, like this:

```
for (i=0;i < box.length;i++)
{
    System.out.print(box[i]);
}
```

Comment: "how??" what? Do you want me to make for you the code?

Comment: I didn't mention that I'll do that, I'm here to help, not to do you work. But I'll show you how to print the array (editing)